# Unit testing function, how to implement call to mock object

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a unit tests for a controller which has an angular scope function that when called, calls a parse.com framework function that makes a call to the parse server and returns the success parameters or the error code.

How do I go about making a mock of that object for the unit test?

The name of the function in the controller's scope is Parse.User.logIn, and here is the mock object I've made for it so far.

```
mockParse = {
      User: {
        logIn: function(_userName, _password, callbackObj) {
            callbackObj.success({
              attributes:{
                username: "testuser",
                email: "testuser@example.com"
              }
            $rootScope.user = _user;
            $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
            $state.go('tab.home');
            };
            callbackObj.error({
              err:{
                code: 101
              }
              if (err.code == 101){
                $scope.error.message = "invalid login credentials";
              } else {
                $scope.error.message = "Unexpected error"
              }
            });
        }
      }
    }
```

Did I do that right? Do I have to make different objects for different callback responses, the error and the success?

When I put it in the test, where do I inject it? Do I place it in the controller, like this?:

```
    ctrl = $controller("LoginCtrl", {
        $scope: $scope,
        Parse: mockParse
    });
```

Here's the actual function:

```
 Parse.User.logIn(($scope.user.username) , $scope.user.password, {
        success: function(_user) {
            console.log('Login Success');
            console.log('user = ' + _user.attributes.username);
            console.log('email = ' + _user.attributes.email);
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $rootScope.user = _user;
            $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
            $state.go('tab.home');
        },
        error: function(user, err) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            // The login failed. Check error to see why.
            if (err.code === 101) {
                $scope.error.message = 'Invalid login credentials';
            } else {
                $scope.error.message = 'An unexpected error has ' +
                    'occurred, please try again.';
            }
            console.log('error message on Parse.User.logIn: ' + $scope.error.message);
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Preface: I am not well versed with Parse.js (nor jasmine for that matter)

I would recommend you go and grab [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org) - super effective and (after some time) easy to use for mocking/stubbing/spying.

---

Start off by not worrying about the internal implementation of the `Parse` object, we're only interested in `input` and `output` of our dependencies when in a unit testing setting. There should be no reason to stub out a service object in that fine grade detail.

---

**beforeEach**

```
var $scope, Parse, createController;

beforeEach(function () {
  Parse = {};

  module('your_module', function ($provide) {
    // Provide "Parse" as a value in your module.
    $provide.value('Parse', Parse);
  });

  inject(function ($controller, $injector) {
    $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    Parse  = $injector.get('Parse'); // equal to: {} (at this point)

    createController = function () {
      return $controller('LoginCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        Parse:  Parse
      });
    };
  });

  Parse.user = {};
  Parse.user.login = sinon.stub();
});
```

Parse is now entirely stubbed out. It will be an empty object that is then provided to the module, exposed in our spec, injected into our controller and then decorated with stubbed out methods matching those of the actual implementation (only by name, of course).

---

### expectation(s)

What you should be testing in your controller spec, is not the internal behaviour of the `Parse` service, but rather that your controller is calling the methods of `Parse` with the correct parameters.

After that, you can go on to test what *your controller*, and *its associated $scope* does in reaction to the `Parse.user.login()` response.

---

### it's

*Note: I am writing these specs with the [mocha](http://mochajs.org/)/[chai](http://chaijs.com/guide/installation/) syntax - adopt the jasmine style as you see fit (not sure how it plays with sinon.js to be quite honest)*

```
it('calls the Parse method', function () {
  createController();

  $scope.login('username', 'pw', angular.noop);

  expect(Parse.user.login).to.have
    .been.calledOnce.and.calledWith('username', 'pw', angular.noop);
});

context('Parse response', function () {
  it('failed', function () {
    Parse.user.login.returns({ status: 'super_error' });

    createController();

    $scope.login('a', 'b', angular.noop);

    expect(/* expect that something on $scope happened? */);
  });

  it('was succesful', function () {
    Parse.user.login.returns({ status: 'great_success', data: {} });

    createController();

    $scope.login('a', 'b', angular.noop);

    expect(/* expect that something on $scope happened? */);
  });
});
```

---

That is how I would write it. But - looking at the [Parse.user.logIn docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.User.html#.logIn) we can see that the method returns a `promise`.

As such, you will need to take the following steps to effectively stub out the correct behaviour:

```
var $q; 

// combine this beforeEach block with the first one we wrote. 
beforeEach(function () {
  inject(function ($injector) {
    $q = $injector.get('$q');
  });
});

context('parse.user.login', inject(function ($timeout) {
  var success, error, opts;

  beforeEach(function () {
    success = sinon.stub();
    error   = sinon.stub();

    opts = {
      success: success,
      error:   error
    };
  });

  it('failed', function () {
    Parse.user.logIn.returns($q.reject({ status: 'bad_error' });
    createController();

    $scope.login('a', 'b', opts);
    $timeout.flush(); // Either this, or $rootScope.$digest or .notify(done) to flush the promise.

    expect(error).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });

  it('was successful', function () {
    Parse.user.logIn.returns($q.when({ status: 'yay!', data: {} });
    createController();

    $scope.login('a', 'b', opts);
    $timeout.flush(); // Either this, or $rootScope.$digest or .notify(done) to flush the promise.

    expect(success).to.have.been.calledOnce;  
  });
}));
```

Comment: I actually just noticed that my glob pattern didn't find the parse.js file and that's why I was getting the Parse undefined error. Now I added it, and had to put my initialization keys in the beforeEach, which I did, and now I'm getting an error that reads `Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.`

What's going on with that now? Does this still call for sinon stubs?

Comment: Well, your mockParse object isnt setting up any spies by the look of what you've shown us. Plus, as I said, it is way too detailed - you don't need/want all of that. I will always recommed sinon as it is a dedicated library for spying/stubbing/mocking, whereas Jasmine is not.